# Which mathematical tool or method should I use to compare two matrices most efficiently?

Tags: matrices, convolution

I have two matrices(the first one is mxm, while the second one is nxn, m>n). They store data pertaining to human speech. The second matrix contains a data segment that acts like an acoustic "signature". I need to find where this data occurs in the first matrix. Which mathematical tool(s) or method(s) can I use to get it done? I know convolution can help me out but is this the best(more importantly fastest) way?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: Say the first matrix is [2 3 4;3 4 2; 1 2 1] while the second matrix is [4.1 2.1;2.1 1.2]. The second matrix most closely matches the lower right sub-section of the first matrix. I would then conclude that the signature(second matrix) occurs in the lower right sub-section of the first matrix(the data). How do I automate this mathematically?

Comment: @user1155386: Is your data always integers or are the real valued? If the latter, it is not so easy.

Comment: they are real-valued, can you please point me to some usable tricks or techniques?

Comment: It is strange that you encode *sound* as a square matrix. Usually matrices store two-dimensional data. The problem of finding a piece of one matrix in another comes up in *image registration*, which is a topic on [dsp.se]. ([They have a tag for it](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-registration)). [This question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/517) seems relevant to your problem. You may be able to get an answer there, but do not expect any magic math formula that solves your problem... it's a job for a sophisticated specialized algorithm.

Comment: @40 votes: thanks a lot! the problem you pointed to is quite similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [Cross Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) is the method you are looking for. Note that implementation using a [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) instead of the brute force definition is much more efficient.

A nice example for 2D matrices (in this case images), can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/registering-an-image-using-normalized-cross-correlation.html).